# Scrolling inside coordinatorlayout with espresso

Tags: java, android, android-testing, android-espresso

Does anyone know if it is or isn't possible to scroll inside a coordinatorlayout with espresso?

e.g. scroll down the page and see if something is displayed to the user. I can't seem to find anything on Google or the espresso page and can't think of any other ideas right now.

Essentially I want to test visibility so maybe there's another way? I can test the correct text is being displayed but not that it's been set to visible. As far as I know "isDisplayed" is the only command to check for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your post is a bit messy. Please in few words sat what you want to test like: I want to check Toolbar title and visibility of the view. Also if you can please add your xml code and Java if you're using RecyclerView or similar

Comment: I want to scroll down in a "android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView" inside a "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" layout. I want to scroll down to a textView and check that it is visible. I'm sorry that I can't be any clearer than that. If you don't know how to do it you need not answer. Calling my post messy is a bit over the top.

Comment: It looks like it's probably possible with a custom viewAction. If I end up implementing something I'll post back. It's not that important I just wanted to know if there was something I was missing; an out of the box way to do it.

Comment: Ok I found what I was looking for (close enough). There is a viewAction called "withEffectiveVisibility" which tests visibility even if it's not in view. Being able to scroll as well would be nice though.

Comment: check this: http://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-espresso/#/, you would here custom matchers for coordinateLayout

Comment: scrollTo() in ViewActions.java file to able to scroll to view in scroll view.

Comment: @PrakhaRaM Since this post is so old now I've forgotten exactly where I was trying to do this. I seem to have forgotten to update the post as I usually do. Anyway I have another project that also has a coordinatorLayout and I'm able to scroll, and it does include scrollTo. I don't know if maybe at the time there was a problem doing this with coordinatorLayout or not, but it certainly works now. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it. E.g. I have this "onView(withText("text")).perform(scrollTo()).check(matches(isDisplayed()))" which works, and obviously the scrollTo is they key.

Answer (score 1):

**scrollTo()** in **ViewActions.java** file to able to scroll to view in scroll view.